# What is the role of WindowDestroyer class in Java? (googling to find)

Tags: java

What is the role of WindowDestroyer class in Java? 
I am studying Java in university. We are studying the Applet chapter and this class came in play.

Where can I find more about this class to understand its behavior and use ?

---

It was a fool question.
I could find the answer in goolge.

Comment: do you know Google?!

Answer (score 2):

I remember the WindowDestroyer class from a textbook I read in the past. WindowDestroyer objects are used by being attached to JFrame objects as listeners. WindowDestroyer will end the program's execution when the JFrame is closed (when the user clicks the JFrame's object.)

Please note that WindowDestroyer is custom class that extends the WindowAdapter class. It is used by the textbook to prevent the tutorial programs from endlessly running. It is not a part of the Java Class Library.

Answer (score 1):

As per JavaDoc : http://ccdb.ucsd.edu/software/data/downloadToolJavaDoc/net/nbirn/ccdb/srb/gui/WindowDestroyer.html

> public class WindowDestroyer extends java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
>
> Description: A Class for closing the application

Contain

```
void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e)
```

> Closing the program.